# Reading float input as int and infinte loop

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to handle human error where if I enter incorrect input like a float value, the program prompts again for the input.

I did this by checking if `scanf` doesn't return the correct number of input scanned (3 here) then it asks again.

But instead am getting infinite loop if a enter "5.4(float) 3 2" or "4 5.4(float) 3" as input and get int values if "5 4 3.2" given as input.

I want to know why this is happening.

I know workarounds like using multiple `scanf`. But I want to know the reason.
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int a,b,c,largest,error;
    do{
       printf("Enter three numbers to find largest:");
       error = scanf("%d %d %d",&a,&b,&c);
    }while(error != 3);
}
```

Comment: The reason is simple. `scanf` stops as soon as it reaches any input that doesn't match. Any unmatched input is not consumed. So every `scanf` call is just continuously failing on the same input.

Comment: "5 4 3.2" can be read as three ints, then a period, then a '2'. First read the input into strings, then verify the contents of the strings.

Comment: If you want to read a line and then parse it, why not use a function that reads a line?

Comment: @kaylum yes you are right after lot of thinking i understood everything after "." remained in buffer and it was junk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"5.4 3 2"` and `"4 5.4 3"` are relatively simple top handle, because when a '.' is consumed by `scanf()`, it immediately learns that there must be something wrong.

However, `"4 3 5.4"` is not so trivial. After `scanf()` consumes `"4 3 5"`, it returns 3 to indicate that 3 integers are scanned successfully, leaving `".4"` in `stdin`. Therefore, the return value of a `scanf()` will **not** be enough for this case.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a, b, c, error;
    do
    {
        printf("Enter three numbers to find largest:");
        error = scanf(" %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);
        if (getchar() != '\n')
        {
            error = 0;
            scanf("%*[^\n]");
        }
    }
    while(error != 3);
    return 0;
}
```

The `scanf("%*[^\n]");` is used to discard all characters in `stdin` until a '\n'. And the space leading `"%d %d %d"` tells `scanf()` to discard one or more whitespace characters(including ' ', '\n' and '\t') until the first non-whitespace character is met.

---

In fact, you don't even have to check the return value of `scanf()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a, b, c;
    for(;;)
    {
        printf("Enter three numbers to find largest:");
        scanf(" %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);
        if (getchar() == '\n')
        {
            break; // successful
        }
        scanf("%*[^\n]");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: actually even the cases like "5.4 3 2" and "4 5.4 3" aren't so simple everything after "." remained in buffer and scanf returns 1 and 2 in these cases respectively.In next loop when scanf is called again in my code ".4 3 2" and ".4 3" remains in buffer and since it cant be used by "%d" scnaf never even asked for input from user.

Comment: i like your approach of using scanf("%*[^\n]"); i didnt know that.Thank you

Comment: @jerrytom Yes, and it is the absence of `scanf("%*[^\n]");` that causes the OP's problem.

Comment: @jerrytom Oh, you're the OP. I didn't notice this :-)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that I know is reading a string line and then you have to try to convert it to your data types.

In this case for example, if you find a "." or "," you can show a error msg.

To convert your string to your data types, you can use [sscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/)

If you use scanf, some characters can keep in the stdin (standard input) buffer, so next time that you use scanf you can get old characters.